# Getting this error Ambiguous use of 'text'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created plants entity in firebase db, I want to add another value of "plantId" for some functionality. For this I am creating an random string id and passing it to plant object to be saved in db, but I am getting an error 'Ambiguous use of 'text'. I searched a lot but can't find any solution. please check my code below:

```
let plantId = NSUUID().uuidString
let plant = ["plantName": self.plantNameField.text, "plantType": self.plantTypeField.text, "plantLocation": self.plantLocationField.text,"userId": userID, "plantImageURL": plantImageURL, "plantId": plantId]
let childUpdates = ["/plants/\(key)": plant]
self.ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

Error occurring in above code line number 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not given enough information, but let's assume your code looks like this. You have an outlet:

```
@IBOutlet var plantNameField : UITextField!
```

And then you say, for example:

```
let plantId = NSUUID().uuidString
let plant = ["plantName": self.plantNameField.text, "plantId":plantId]
```

That is illegal because `self.plantNameField.text` and `plantId` have different types, whereas a dictionary in Swift must have values of the same type. To fix it, you would say:

```
let plant = ["plantName": self.plantNameField.text!, "plantId":plantId]
```

(Note the exclamation mark.)

And similarly for your other `text` entries in the dictionary.

But of course this answer is contingent on the guess that `plantNameField` is indeed a UITextField; you have not shown enough code for me to know whether that is true.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the creation of the "key"

```
    let key = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key
let post = ["uid": userID,
            "author": username,
            "title": title,
            "body": body]
let childUpdates = ["/posts/\(key)": post,
                    "/user-posts/\(userID)/\(key)/": post]
ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

Maybe you already did but take a look at this. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write
The "Key" creation is the only part that is missing.